# NFSv4 and race condition with idmapd, pam_mount and auto mount

Tags: nfs4, rhel8, rhel9

We mount NFSv4+krb5 shares with automount, and it works fine.
We are now trying to mount home directories with nfs4 and automount.
We get the directories mounted, but still get some directories/files mounted as "nobody".
Mounting the same directory manually doesn't give us a problem.
So I decided to mount these home directories using `pam_mount`. It works fine for me, but some users still get `nobody`. If I log to their machine and restart `nfs-imapd`, the ownership of the files gets fixed.

Can this be a race condition between pam_mount/automount and `nfs-idmapd`? If so, any tips on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due a wrong/incomplete regex rule. I was using the regex plugin for idmapd, and something was wrong with the rule. Once it was changed, it all worked again.

Answer (score 0):

NFSv4 stat() owner/group results are transmitted as textual "user@domain" labels instead of UIDs/GIDs. The domain isn't very important, but it needs to match between all clients and servers. (This doesn't affect actual UID-based *access* that the user gets – it only affects the `ls -l` results.)

If you constantly get `nobody`, it's possible that idmapd doesn't know your domain name at boot time. For example, if you do not have your FQDN in /etc/hosts, then idmapd would need to query DNS, and it's possible that it starts before networking (and therefore DNS) becomes available.

Try to define the domain either specifically for idmapd:

```
/etc/idmapd.conf
[General]
Domain = example.com
```

or globally via `hosts`:

```
/etc/hosts
# The server's own IP address (if static)
10.2.3.4 foo.example.com foo
```